# add scrollbar to QGridLayout

Tags: python, pyqt5, qgridlayout

I have a problem with adding a scrollbar to a QGridLayout. I tried some solutions but no difference.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

from QIComboBox import QIComboBox
from risc_fact import FACT


class Page2_MECANIC(QtWidgets.QWizardPage):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Page2_MECANIC, self).__init__(parent)
        self.f = FACT

    def initializePage(self):
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)

        self.select = QLabel(self)
        self.select.setText('FACT')
        self.select.move(20, 20)

        font = QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.select.setFont(font)

        self.labels = []
        count = 0
        for factor in list(self.f.FACT):
            self.risc = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(factor.value)
            self.risc.setChecked(False)
            self.risc.number = ' ' + str(count)
            count += 1
            self.risc.toggled.connect(self.onClicked)
            self.risc_value = self.max_cons()
            self.risc_value_line = self.cls_grav()
            self.labels.append(self.risc)
            self.labels.append(self.risc_value)
            self.labels.append(self.risc_value_line)

        layout.addWidget(self.select, 0, 0)

        row = 1
        col = 0
        for widget in self.labels:
            layout.addWidget(widget, row, col)
            col += 1
            if col == 3:
                row += 1
                col = 0

        button = QPushButton("Save ", self)
        layout.addWidget(button, 20, 2)
        button.pressed.connect(self.find)

        self.setLayout(layout)

    def cls_grav(self):
        list_cls_grav = ['Select',
                                         '(1, 1)', '(1, 2)', '(1, 3)', '(1, 4)', '(1, 5)', '(1, 6)',
                                         '(2, 1)', '(2, 2)', '(2, 3)', '(2, 4)', '(2, 5)', '(2, 6)',
                                         '(3, 1)', '(3, 2)', '(3, 3)', '(3, 4)', '(3, 5)', '(3, 6)',
                                         '(4, 1)', '(4, 2)', '(4, 3)', '(4, 4)', '(4, 5)', '(4, 6)',
                                         '(5, 1)', '(5, 2)', '(5, 3)', '(5, 4)', '(5, 5)', '(5, 6)',
                                         '(6, 1)', '(6, 2)', '(6, 3)', '(6, 4)', '(6, 5)', '(6, 6)',
                                         '(7, 1)', '(7, 2)', '(7, 3)', '(7, 4)', '(7, 5)', '(7, 6)']
        self.comboBox_value = QIComboBox(self)
        self.comboBox_value.addItems(list_cls_grav)

        return self.comboBox_value

    def max_cons(self):
        list_max_cons = ['Select', 'DEC', 'ITM 3-45', "ITM 45-180",
                                           "INV GRD I", "INV GRD II", "INV GRD III"]
        self.comboBox = QIComboBox(self)
        self.comboBox.addItems(list_max_cons)
        return self.comboBox

    def onClicked(self):
        risc = self.sender()
        print("Risc" + risc.number + " is " + str(risc.isChecked()))

    def find(self):
        risc_0 = [self.risc_value.currentText(), self.risc_value_line.currentText()]
        risc_1 = [self.risc1_value.currentText(), self.risc1_value_line.currentText()]
        risc_2 = [self.risc2_value.currentText(), self.risc2_value_line.currentText()]
        risc_3 = [self.risc3_value.currentText(), self.risc3_value_line.currentText()]
        risc_4 = [self.risc4_value.currentText(), self.risc4_value_line.currentText()]
        risc_5 = [self.risc5_value.currentText(), self.risc5_value_line.currentText()]
        risc_6 = [self.risc6_value.currentText(), self.risc6_value_line.currentText()]
        risc_7 = [self.risc7_value.currentText(), self.risc7_value_line.currentText()]
        risc_8 = [self.risc8_value.currentText(), self.risc8_value_line.currentText()]
```

Comment: You can't "add a scrollbar to QGridLayout", because it's a layout manager, not a widget, so use a QScrollArea. In any case, you should only ask one question per post.

Comment: Thanks! Solved with QScrollArea. But I have another question, how can I add a function to next button that return a value which will be used to write into a word document when I press finish button? (Will be more pages (10), and each page will have multiple checkbox and values -> I need to store in a variable and on last page when I press Finish to have another function that will write values into a word file)

Comment: sorry but your question is completely confusing. From what I can understand, anyway, it's completely unrelated to this post, so it's off-topic. If you need some other help, create a new question, but please first of all ensure you followed the [tour], read [ask] good questions and if you need to provide code, always try to make it a [mre].

Comment: @Alin could you please share final answer ? I am also looking to apply a scrollbar on grid layout but didn't get success.  could you please share you solution ?